# How do i get this function to show only one record per time?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

This code retrieves all record from the table and displays. How can i change this so it shows only one record at a time from the table?

```
def printquestion():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('VIT.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    posts = "select que from Questions"
    c.execute(posts)
    conn.commit()
    records = c.fetchall()
    print(records)
    print_q = ''
    for record in records:
        print_q += str(record[0]) + "\n"
    lbl_question = Label(top, text=print_q)
    lbl_question.grid(row=2, column=1)

    conn.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display one record at a time"? What GUI framework are you using? Is it a desktop app, a web app?

Comment: I'm using python and tkinter. It's for a desktop application. By "display one record at a time" I mean I need to access one record from the table i'm referring. There're several records in form of string in the table. I need them to appear one by one after clicking a button. btw I'm really new to python and excuse my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've changed my code so it retrieves and shows only one record per time(iteration)

```
def printquestion():
    global i            
    conn = sqlite3.connect('VIT.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    post_q = "select que from Questions where id=" + str(i)
    c.execute(post_q)
    records = c.fetchone()
    print(records)
    print_q = ''
    for record in records:
        print_q += str(record) + "\n"
    lbl_question = Label(top, text=print_q)
    lbl_question.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

I've given a variable `i=1` outside of this function and called it as a global variable to act as the `id` for the sql query. `i` gets incremented at the end of function as `i+=1` after some more codes. Hope this helps for anyone needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load all your rows from the table to a list of tuples. You then keep track of which row is being displayed using a global variable. When the user clicks on next or previous, you increment or decrement the variable and pick up one data row from the list and put it in the GUI.

You can improve all of this by using a class that contains your data and business logic.

Look into this framework to use data binding: https://github.com/marczellm/tkpf

Read about event driven programming and event loop. You should be loading your data once when the window opens.